# Wordpress Attachment Page Navigate with Keyboard

Tags: wordpress, mousetrap

I'm using WordPress.

I want to navigate my attachment page with **left** and **right** key.

Here is my codes, but not working;

```js
function GoToLocation(url)
  {
    window.location = url;
  }

  Mousetrap.bind("j", function() {
    //alert('j pressed' + document.getElementById("next").href);
    //document.getElementById("next").click();
    window.location=<?php echo $image->next_image_link ?>;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/rainbow-custom.min.js?39e99"></script>
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/mousetrap/mousetrap.js?bc893"></script>
```

If I change that

```
window.location=<?php echo $image->next_image_link ?>;
```

to this

```
window.location="http://mylink.com";
```

script working well. but I can't use WordPress based link (like **next_image_link();**)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did myself,

firstly add this to top

```html
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/rainbow-custom.min.js?39e99"></script>
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/mousetrap/mousetrap.js?bc893"></script>
```

Then add this script too

```
function GoToLocation(url)
  {
    window.location = url;
  }
  Mousetrap.bind("right", function() {
document.getElementById('next-page').click();
  });



function GoToLocation(url)
  {
    window.location = url;
  }
  Mousetrap.bind("left", function() {
document.getElementById('prev-page').click();
  });
```

lastly, put "next-page" , "prev-page" ID to the location of the link tag
for example;

```
<a id="next-page"></a>
```

or

```
<a id="prev-page"></a>
```

So, when you press Left or Right keyboard button, script will work well. See ya

Answer (score 0):

Replace `window.location=<?php echo $image->next_image_link ?>;` with
`window.location="<?php echo $image->next_image_link ?>";`. Your string declariation is not valid so it can't work.

PHP doesn't echo link with inverted commas.

Edit: Wordpress doesn't print just the URL. It prints link element. So the solution will be

1. Binding to existing navigation
2. Using regex to cut off the htmt syntax

   `var element = '<?php echo $image->next_image_link ?>';
    window.location = element.match(/href="([^"]*)/)[1];`

Comment: thanks for your help, but when i press "j" with your edited code, page is reloading the same url.