# Adding keyboard arrow navigation to custom js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, navigation

I am using wordpress and my content looks like this

```
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/2/"><img src="blah1.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/3/"><img src="blahab.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/4/"><img src="blahco.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/5/"><img src="blahneat.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>
```

I have a custom javascript that loads the next image when the user clicks on the image. Now I want to add left & right keyboard arrow navigation to this script and I don't know how I can I implement to it since I'm not familiar with javascript.

```
$('body').on('click', '.image-wrap', function(e) { // listen for 'click' on our '.image-wrap' element
  e.preventDefault();  // Prevents default behavior on the a element

  $.ajax({

    url: $(this).find( 'a' ).attr( 'href' ), // the url we are fetching by ajax
    success: function (response) {

      newImg = $(response).find('.image-wrap').html(), // get the new href link and image from the response, contained in div.image-wrap

      $( 'div.image-wrap' ).html( newImg ); // set the new html for our inner div

    }
  }).fail(function (data) {

    if ( window.console && window.console.log ) {

      console.log( data );  // log failure to console

    }

  });

});
```

**EDIT:**
By pressing the right arrow key I want it to click the ajax link that is inside image-wrap div which should load the next image. If pressing the left arrow key it should go back to the previous image. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Still not clear.  Which image-wrap div should the arrow key act on?  You have four.

Comment: Well on wordpress it will show only one image-wrap div on the page cause the <!--nextpage--> tag will split those divs into multiple pages. So the arrow keys should be focusing on the one image-wrap div on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mousetrap.

```js
function GoToLocation(url)
  {
    window.location = url;
  }
  Mousetrap.bind("right", function() {
document.getElementById('next-image').click();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/rainbow-custom.min.js?39e99"></script>
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/mousetrap/mousetrap.js?bc893"></script>

<div class="image-wrap"><a id="next-image" class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/2/"><img src="blah1.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a id="next-image" class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/3/"><img src="blahab.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a id="next-image" class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/4/"><img src="blahco.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a id="next-image" class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/5/"><img src="blahneat.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>
```

if you are use attachment.php or image.php based gallery. you can also use this : [Wordpress Attachment Page Navigate with Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082930/wordpress-attachment-page-navigate-with-keyboard)

Comment: What about the left arrow key? I'd like it to go back a page/image

Comment: can you show me an example page? so i can write anything about that.

Comment: its ok. but also you must write here php codes about your image gallery page. its html printed codes. you must write php source codes.

Comment: I'm not really using any custom php. It's just a standard wordpress post using the <!--nextpage--> tag to split content into multiple pages and embedded custom javascript

Comment: i cant help you about that.sorry. but I would recommend, you can use default wordpress gallery. and you can do that : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082930/wordpress-attachment-page-navigate-with-keyboard).
Here is working example (use right and left arrow key) : [link](http://www.oyunfest.com/dunyanin-en-iyi-yaris-oyunu-gran-turismo-sport-olabilir.html/gran-turismo-sport-1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a handler to the document `keyup` event, and test the key code for the event. A handy reference to key codes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Below is an example.  When you run it, click in the output panel to give it focus before testing the keys.

```js
var selectedIndex = 0;

var elements = $('.navigable').toArray();
var maxElements = elements.length;

function nextSelection() {
  selectedIndex++;
  if(selectedIndex >= maxElements) {
    selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  selectElement();
}

function prevSelection() {
  selectedIndex--;
  if(selectedIndex < 0) {
    selectedIndex = maxElements - 1;
  }
  selectElement();
}

function selectElement() {
  $('.navigable').removeClass('selected');
  $(elements[selectedIndex]).addClass('selected');
}

handleKeyUp = function(ev) {
  if(ev.keyCode == 37) { // left arrow key
    prevSelection();
  } 
  if(ev.keyCode == 39) { // right arrow key
    nextSelection();
  } 
  if(ev.keyCode == 27) { // escape key
    $(document).off('keyup', handleKeyUp);
  }   
}

$(document).on('keyup', handleKeyUp);
selectElement();
```

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #fee;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.selected {
  background: #faa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigable">1</div>
<div class="navigable">2</div>
<div class="navigable">3</div>
<br>
<br>
<p> Click in this panel to give it focus.  Use arrow keys to navigate between divs.  Press `ESC` to disable `keyup` handler.</p>
```

Comment: your script seems to select divs only but I want the arrow keys to click on the image link or go back previous image link. How can I do this?

Comment: Which arrow keys do you want to do what, exactly?  You said you wanted arrow key navigation.  My answer shows how to handle keyup events with a general example.  How you choose to handle the keyup events, depends on what you're trying to do, which is unclear.  Please describe a full scenario in your question with details on what should happen when a user presses a given arrow key before and after clicking one of your ajax links.